# How to override keys in Xamarin Android Manifest

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, google-api, xamarin.android

I'm using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) guide to working with maps in Xamarin.

It says I should use different values of the key

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWValueGoesHere" />
```

for debug and release builds; the debug version should use an API key that contains SHA-1 certificates from `debug.keystore`, which has well-known default passwords.

In live mode, I should use SHA-1 certificates from my custom keystore files, whose passwords only I know. The live API key and SHA-1 certificate work in the live APK, but not in the debug build. This makes sense, I guess. I should have one Google Android API key for debugging, and one for production.

What I don't want to do is have this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="<My Debug API Key>" />
<!--<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="<My Release API Key>" />-->
```

...changing the commented out section depending on whether I'm doing a debug or release build. Is there a more efficient way to do this (something like config transforms in ASP.NET applications)?

I've done some searching, and there are some automatically applied debug overrides, but it doesn't seem like I have a great deal of control over the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use assembly level `MetaData` attributes to define tags within the Manifest's Application element and by using conditional compilation:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: MetaData("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY", Value = "DebugKEYValue")]
#else
[assembly: MetaData("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY", Value = "ReleaseKEYValue")]
#endif
```

Depending upon build type, this will result in:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="DebugValue" />
```

Or:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="android.app.Application">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="ReleaseKEYValue" />
```

Comment: Nice. I'll give it a go.